# Change contents of <span> on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a `<span>` that I'm trying to change the contents of on click. I've followed a few tutorials but I can't seem to get it right so that it will change. I'm using unicode characters so I think I need to use `.html()` instead of `.text()` but I could be wrong. Any reason why this shouldn't work?

Here is the source that I'm working with

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdownheader").click(function() {
    $("#childList").toggle("slow");
    if ($("#droparrow").html() == '&rtrif;') {
      $("#droparrow").html('&dtrif;');
    } else {
      $("#droparrow").html('&rtrif;');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdownheader">Expected Outcomes of a Corporate Course <span id="droparrow">&dtrif;</span></div>
<div id="childList">
  <ul>
    <li>A better relationship with your coworkers.</li>
    <li>A High Trust and open enivornment.</li>
    <li>A safe and fun environment to work in.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no `class="droparrow"` element in your HTML. It's `id="droparrow"`, so the selector should be `#droparrow`.

Comment: @Barmar Whoops, thought I fixed that. It's fixed now. Now it'll change once, but it wont change back on click.

Comment: The problem is that `.html()` doesn't return the entity code, it returns the Unicode character that it translates to. Try `console.log($("#droparrow").html())` to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because this check:

```
 if ($("#droparrow").html() == '&rtrif;')
```

Always evaluates false. A better way to do this might be to store a `data-expanded` attribute on your element and use that to determine whether to toggle - remembering to update the data item each click.

```js
$(".dropdownheader").click(function() {
    $("#childList").toggle("slow");
    if($("#droparrow").data("expanded") == "1") {
        $("#droparrow").data("expanded","0").html('&dtrif;');
    } else {
        $("#droparrow").data("expanded","1").html('&rtrif;');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdownheader">Expected Outcomes of a Corporate Course <span id="droparrow" data-expanded="1">&rtrif;</span></div>
    <div id="childList">
        <ul>
            <li>A better relationship with your coworkers.</li>
            <li>A High Trust and open enivornment.</li>
            <li>A safe and fun environment to work in.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help! I'll accept the answer when StackOverflow lets me haha